# search by match in react and output only matching elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

made the logic to search for specific elements

but when outputting this component, only 000000 is output instead of the specified
meaning

my code:

```
{
            value.stats.map((stat:any) => {
                if(stat.effort === 1){
                    return dataPosibleValue.map((all:any) => {
                        if(all.highest_stat.name === stat.stat.name){
                            return all.possible_values.find((number:any)=>{
                                if(number === stat.base_stat % 5){
                                    return <p>svin</p>
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
        })}
```

all

```
    descriptions: Array(3)
0: {description: "Fuit rapidement", language: {…}}
1: {description: "Huye rápido", language: {…}}
2: {description: "Quick to flee", language: {…}}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
gene_modulo: 4
highest_stat: {name: "speed", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"}
id: 30
possible_values: (6) [4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29]
```

stat

```
base_stat: 65
effort: 1
stat: {name: "special-attack", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/4/"}
```

looking at console.log (value.name) outputs the correct value. But on return, nothing happens, but only the output of 000000

```
return value.stats.map((stat:any) => {
    if(stat.effort === 1){
       console.log(stat) 
        return dataPosibleValue.map((all:any) => {
            if("special-defense" === stat.stat.name)
                return all.possible_values.filter((number:any)=>{
                    if(number === stat.base_stat % 5){
                        return console.log(value.name)// pokemon name
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.filter()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: What is `svin`? It would be helpful in general to have minimal example values for each of the specified variables so that respondents can reason about your logic.

Comment: Also, to expand on Jonas Hendel's comment, `map` is meant to return a single value for *every* single element in the mapped array. If you want to return values for only *some matching* elements, `filter` is the correct approach.

Comment: stat : base_stat: 65
effort: 1
stat: {name: "special-attack", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/4/"} all = descriptions: Array(3)
0: {description: "Fuit rapidement", language: {…}}
1: {description: "Huye rápido", language: {…}}
2: {description: "Quick to flee", language: {…}}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
gene_modulo: 4
highest_stat: {name: "speed", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"}
id: 30
possible_values: (6) [4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29]

Comment: Referring to your final code block, the return value of `console.log` is `undefined`, and the mapped value for any element in `value.stats` for which `stat.effort !== 1`  is also undefined, as you do not specify a return value for those elements (again, I think what you really want to use here is `filter` and not `map`). You still haven't told us what `svin` is, so I can't comment on why your original code returns zeros.

Comment: svin-pig is just a word, I wanted to check the output

Comment: no there is not undefined but a certain value, namely the name of the pokemon and it is displayed without problems

Comment: In the example data you supplied, `all.highest_stat.name` (`"speed"`) does not match `stat.stat.name` (`"special-attack"`). Therefore, there is no return value in your original code block, or, equivalently, the return is `undefined`. I don't know offhand how `undefined` is rendered, but it could be that the zeros you are seeing are those undefined values.